# Requesting new user account and sending email

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following on my page.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x0Lk7wz/5/)

The current functionality is that whenever a user requests an account on the home screen, a popup is displayed saying that we have received your request and you will be provided access after it is reviewed. This is working fine.

Now we also want to send an e-mail to the user with the same details. Can this be achieved. We are using HTML, CSS and Javscript.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/3x0Lk7wz/3/
```

Comment: Please, don't try to skirt around the requirement to put code in you question when linking to a jsfiddle. It's there because a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needs to be *inside* the question and not just linked.

Comment: Limited to only html, css and javascript, you will have to make your javascript code to post it to your backend function through ajax which will in turn send the email with the data.

Comment: Sorry didnt understand you? Can you elaborate? M not good at coding..

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]